# 'vector iterators incompatible'

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

This question has been asked a number of times on SO, but the answers do not apply to my situation, AFAICT. The following piece of code is triggering the error immediately upon hitting `i != std::end(observers_);`.

```
void VisualGeometry::SignalPopPointFlags(const Point_2r& p,
                                         const uint32_t msec_delay) const {
    for(auto i = std::begin(observers_); i != std::end(observers_); ++i)
        (*i)->SlotPopPointFlags(p, msec_delay);
}
```

Looking into `<vector>`, the following triggers the error:

```
void _Compat(const _Myiter& _Right) const
{   // test for compatible iterator pair
    if (this->_Getcont() == 0
        || this->_Getcont() != _Right._Getcont())
        {   // report error
            _DEBUG_ERROR("vector iterators incompatible");
            _SCL_SECURE_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }
}
```

Since I am not comparing iterators from different containers, it seems like the first check for `this->_Getcont() == 0` might be the problem, but I'm not sure how to tell.

The same problem occurs if I swap out begin(vec)/end(vec) for vec.begin()/vec.end().

I'm a little lost as to how this can happen. Any advice on how to move forward with debugging this?

The VisualGeometry class is designed to forward signals that it receives onward to whichever objects are watching it. Here are relevant code snippets:

```
class VisualGeometry : public IGeometryObserver, public IObservableGeometry {
public:
    void SlotPushSegmentFlags(const Segment_2r& s, const uint32_t flags,
                              const uint32_t msec_delay = 0) override;
    void SlotPopSegmentFlags(const Segment_2r& s,
                             const uint32_t msec_delay = 0) override;
    void SignalPushSegmentFlags(const Segment_2r& s, const uint32_t flags,
                                const uint32_t msec_delay = 0) const override;
    void SignalPopSegmentFlags(const Segment_2r& s,
                               const uint32_t msec_delay = 0) const override;
    /* snip */    
private:
    std::vector<IGeometryObserver*> observers_;
};

void VisualGeometry::SlotPushSegmentFlags(const Segment_2r& s,
                                          const uint32_t flags,
                                          const uint32_t msec_delay) {
    SignalPushSegmentFlags(s, flags, msec_delay);
}

void VisualGeometry::SlotPopPointFlags(const Point_2r& p,
                                       const uint32_t msec_delay) {
    SignalPopPointFlags(p, msec_delay);
}

/* etc... */
```

Comment: What does `SlotPopPointFlags` do? Does it modify the vector you are iterating over, by any chance?

Comment: What element type is `observers_` holding?

Comment: Also, aside from @IgorTandetnik's excellent point, are there other threads that are changing `observers_` while this loop is happening? Or other crazy concurrency bugs (e.g., insufficient synchronisation)?

Comment: Other UB like use of dangling pointers, buffer overflow of nearby stack variables, etc. could also cause this sort of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing to check is to see if you are modifying the `vector` you are iterating over as you iterate over it.

See if this eliminates the problem:

```
void VisualGeometry::SignalPopPointFlags(const Point_2r& p,
                                         const uint32_t msec_delay) const {
  auto obs = observers_;
  for(auto i = std::begin(obs); i != std::end(obs); ++i)
    (*i)->SlotPopPointFlags(p, msec_delay);
}
```

Dealing with that kind of problem is tricky, and often a sign you have a design problem.

In general, when calling a sequence of callbacks, if that callback has any way to reach the sequence you are iterating over and change it or its members, you need to add in some lifetime management code, and determine what it means for another callback to be sent when one is currently being sent, and what it means if callbacks are installed or uninstalled while callbacks are being called.

A simple rule is that "you don't get callbacks if you are installed while callbacks are being installed", but if you uninstall your callback, you will not get called.

To produce this effect, my callbacks tend to be containers of `weak_ptr`s to `std::function`s.  When you install your callback, you pass in a `std::function`, which I then copy into a `shared_ptr`.  I spawn a `weak_ptr` off that, and store it in my callback container.

I then return the `shared_ptr` to the code that is installing the callback.  This `shared_ptr` is the lifetime token: so long as it (or copies of it) is valid, I will continue to make callbacks on it.

In my broadcast function, I first sweep my container for obsolete `weak_ptr`s, then copy the container to a local `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<std::function<void(message)>>>`.

I then iterate over this container, doing a `.lock()` to get a `std::shared_ptr<std::function<void(message)>>`, then if it is valid calling it.

If a broadcast is triggered when I'm broadcasting, it happens.  (if this happens too often, I'll blow my stack, but that is another problem).  If someone adds a callback, I'm fine.  If someone removes a callback, I'm fine.

If things are multi-threaded, I am not locked when iterating over the local `std::vector`, but am locked while clearing the `weak_ptr`s that aren't valid, and when cloning the sequence of `weak_ptr`s, or when adding/removing callbacks to the `vector<weak_ptr<function<...>>>`.